# How to include HTML fragments via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to include a HTML fragment inside another HTML page like so (below), via JQuery, but nothing works. What could I be doing wrong?

The folder structure looks as follows:

```
---> Project_Root --> jquery --> jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min
                  --> index.html
                  --> parts  --> header.html
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min"></script>

  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#navbar").load("parts/header.html"); 
    });
  </script> 

  <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navbar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

header.html:

```
<p> This is my include file </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual `jQuery` library is missing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min"></script>
```

Migrate plugin is used when you want to use some removed/deprecated methods of jQuery which is not in the latest jQuery library.